# R: Subsetting returns "0 obs."

Tags: r, time, subset

I'm trying to subset my dataset 'eggdat' for daytime and nighttime hours. This:

```
'data.frame':   54847 obs. of  10 variables:
$ year  : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
$ month : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ day   : int  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
$ hour  : int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
$ minute: int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ second: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
$ Roll  : num  -159 179 -164 -155 -137 ...
$ Pitch : num  -31.36 -41.05 -23.85 -6.62 -9.13 ...
$ Yaw   : num  -71.8 -113.3 -67.2 -140.2 -78.2 ...
$ temp1 : num  25 33.5 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 ...
```

Subsetting for daytime works fine:

```
daytime <- eggdat[eggdat$hour >= 7 & eggdat$hour <= 20, ]

'data.frame':   18847 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ year  : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ month : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ day   : int  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
 $ hour  : int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 $ minute: int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ second: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Roll  : num  -159 179 -164 -155 -137 ...
 $ Pitch : num  -31.36 -41.05 -23.85 -6.62 -9.13 ...
 $ Yaw   : num  -71.8 -113.3 -67.2 -140.2 -78.2 ...
 $ temp1 : num  25 33.5 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 ...
```

Doing exactly the same thing for nighttime, however, returns a subset with 0 observations:

```
nighttime <- eggdat[eggdat$hour <= 7 & eggdat$hour >= 21, ]

'data.frame':   0 obs. of  10 variables:
$ year  : int 
$ month : int 
$ day   : int 
$ hour  : int 
$ minute: int 
$ second: int 
$ Roll  : num 
$ Pitch : num 
$ Yaw   : num 
$ temp1 : num
```

I really don't know what to do.. I tried using `subset` , but without success.. I also tried `eggdat$hour <- as.factor(eggdat$hour)`, but couldn't get it to work either.

Even more confusingly, adding the quotation marks in the subset function (`daytime <- eggdat[eggdat$hour >= '7' & eggdat$hour <= '20', ]` and `nighttime <- eggdat[eggdat$hour <= '7' & eggdat$hour >= '21', ]`) resulted in the daytime subset containing '0 obs.', but the nighttime subset working fine, so it's just the other way around!
Daytime: `'data.frame': 0 obs. of  10 variables:`
Nighttime:

```
'data.frame':   28800 obs. of  10 variables:
$ year  : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
$ month : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ day   : int  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
$ hour  : int  21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 ...
$ minute: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ second: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
$ Roll  : num  65.8 65.8 66.1 65.6 65.6 ...
$ Pitch : num  6.35 6.34 6.24 6.4 6.27 ...
$ Yaw   : num  171 172 174 176 176 ...
$ temp1 : num  41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 41.5 ...
```

I really don't know what to do, I'm very confused by all of this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `eggdat[eggdat$hour <= 7 | eggdat$hour >= 21, ]`

`x < 7 & x > 21` translates to x smaller than 7 **AND** larger than 21

`x < 7 | x > 21` translates to x smaller than 7 **OR** larger than 21